# TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on string... even after using JSON.Parse?? (MongoDB /Node.js / Twitter API)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter

EDIT - BTW, I am trying to Insert 100 Tweets into the MongoDB database.

I am trying to insert the text of Tweets (using Twitter API) into a MongoDB database and I get `TypeError: Cannot create property _id on string` even after parsing. I bet that it may be an easy and dumb mistake to fix. My code is the following:

EDIT 2 - I edited the code to get the same error Im still having.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: ' ',
  consumer_secret: ' ',
  access_token_key: ' ',
  access_token_secret: ' '});

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
var parser = { useNewUrlParser: true };

    MongoClient.connect(url, parser, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Database created!");
      var dbo = db.db("mydb");
      dbo.createCollection("datos_sentimiento", function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Collection created!");
        db.close();
      });
    });

MongoClient.connect(url, parser, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var cont = 0;

  var params = {q: '@Avengers', count: 100, include_rts: 0, tweet_mode: 'extended', retweeted_status: 'extended'};
  client.get('search/tweets', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if (!error) {
      //console.log(tweets);
      for(var i=0; i < params.count; i++){

        if(tweets.retweeted_status){
          tweets = tweets.retweeted_status;
          var tweet = (JSON.stringify(tweets.statuses[i])+"\n");
          var string = tweet.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
          console.log('hi');
        }
        else{

          //console.log('hi2');
        }

        var tweet = (JSON.stringify(tweets.statuses[i].full_text));
        var string = tweet.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
        var string2 = (JSON.stringify(string)+"\n");

        fs.appendFile("tweet.txt", string2, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
            //console.log('Saved!');
        }); 

        /*console.log(cont);
        cont++;*/

        var myobj = JSON.parse(string2);

        console.log("hi "+myobj);
        dbo.collection("datos_sentimiento").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document inserted");
          db.close();
        });
        //console.log(i+'fdfdfdfdf');

        }
      }
  });
});
```

The error shows the following message:

```
TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on string 'RT @RobertDowneyJr Brace yourselves @Avengers InfinityWar hits the interwebs today httpstcoqvBQ3W8jvc'
```

Comment: mongodb is document object store so you must store it as object instead of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. MongoDB needs (a must have!) to have a document (eg. text = {screen_name: name, text: text}). My correction is the following:

```
var text = JSON.parse(string2);
var myobj = {texto: text};

console.log("hi "+text);
dbo.collection("datos_sentimiento").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Variable `myobj` is string in above case so, please make it to object like this `{myobj}`:

Previous: `dbo.collection("datos_sentimiento").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {`

Modify to : `dbo.collection("datos_sentimiento").insertOne({myobj}, function(err, res) {`

Comment: thank you! my case data needed to put in object